# DOM/xpath usage with php to process external site?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am trying to wrap my head around DOM in order to process an external URL and retrieve a piece of content. So far by looking at some tutorials and such on the interwebs I have come up with this:

```
$url = 'http://www.staticmapper.com/index.php?system=J224442';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLfile($url);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query("//html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/p[2]/span");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo "<br/>[". $element->nodeName. "]";

  }
}
```

However, nothing returns.

The desired output in this case would be "J244". Can anyone give me pointers/suggestions on how to achieve this goal?

Thanks.

Comment: In this case the expression `'//span[@class="lowsec"]` would have worked too.

Comment: The value "lowsec" is going to vary during implementation (it could be one of 9 values).

Comment: Fair enough, I get anxious when I see expressions like you have there :)

Comment: I wish there was an easier way. I am trying to use this data and insert it in a database for over 2900 unique rows (each returns a different string). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135485/update-column-for-entire-table-with-different-values-sql-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did modifications from your code. Just omitted `tbody` from the query. Consider this example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.staticmapper.com/index.php?system=J224442');

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query("/html/body/table[2]/tr[1]/td[1]/p[2]/span");
foreach($elements as $value) {
    echo $value->nodeValue; // J244
}
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RGM7Y4)

Comment: Why not just use `->loadHTMLFile()`? Now you have three lines of code instead of one. Btw, `//html` can be just `/html` because it already ought to be the top element anyway.

Comment: @Jack yeah i edited it, while testing i just used file_get_contents because i wanted to see to debug what happens, thanks for the heads up

Comment: @Jack according to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) `loadHtml()` expects a string. So with the edited answer `var_dump($dom->saveHtml())` (expectedly) returns `string(193) "http://www.staticmapper.com/index.php?system=J224442"` ... [Another sample output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/e9hmqZ)

Comment: @Havelock Where did you see me mention `->loadHTML()`?

Comment: @Jack, my bad, didn't see that was edited as well. Sorry for the foolish comment.