# Update column for entire table with different values (SQL, PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to automate a task of inserting a string value into a table in every row. The string varies, however will not be longer than 18 characters. This is what I came up with off the top of my head:

```
<?php
include "db/connect.php";
include "db/select.php";
include "functions/getStatics.php";

if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $all = dbSelect("SELECT * FROM wh_systems"); //returns 2400 rows (entire table)
    foreach($all as $r) {
        $statics = getStatics($r->name); //returns string to be entered, different for every row
        $sql = "UPDATE wh_systems
                SET statics='$statics'
                WHERE name='$r->name'";
        if($update = $db->query($sql)) {
            echo $db->affected_rows;
        }
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WH Tools</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id = "edit" name = "edit" method = "get" action = "edit.php">
            <input type = "submit" name="submit" value ="Start"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I feel like something is very wrong about the code, and indeed when I run it only about *44* rows are updated before some form of timeout happens. Being that there are 2498 rows total, this does not work.

What other method can I use to achieve this result? Suggestions? Still learning PHP and cant think of any other way to automate this.

Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you limiting to only those 44 rows with the where clause: `WHERE name='$r->name'` ?

Comment: There are no repeating names - the `WHERE name='$r->name'` only restricts which row is updated (it's one at a time).

Comment: What does `getStatics()` do? Can you replicate the function in SQL?

Comment: `getStatics()` returns the string that I want to enter into the row. Here is the code: http://codepad.viper-7.com/QPuvV4 .